# Two combobox in javafx make program unstable

Tags: combobox, javafx-2

I have applications that have multiple combobox and I noticed that when you select one combobox and then pick another application and you come back to the application picking another combobox, the application start switching between the comboxboxes. I cannot even debug to see what's happening. You can try a simple application like the sample in oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/ComboBoxSample.java.html
and then (1) pick email combobox, (2) pick priority combobox (3) go to any other application (e.g. excel, windows explorer) (4) pick email combobox. It will start switching back and forth between combobox. 
I am using windows 7 ultimate 64 bits, java 1.7.21.
Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce the bug on my machine (Windows 7 64bits, java 1.7.0_25 64bits)

If this is not a problem with your implementation then it might come from your version of java. Can you install the [newer version of the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and try again ? Maybe this will solve your problem.